# How to get the string of values as a result of a basic formula?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get a list of values for the volume of a sphere at different radii. I have the list of radii in a text file and I want to plug in each individual radii in the formula for the volume and get the volume.

This is the code I have written

```
radius = pd.read_csv("radius.txt", header=None)
data.head()
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
pie=3.1415926535898
volume=(4.0/3.0)*pie*(radius*radius*radius)  
print("volume" + str(volume))
```

But, the compiler reports an error. This is the error reported.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):              
File "/tmp/sessions/b0eeca5f0a91ca17/main.py", line 40, in                                  <module>
    data.head()
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Is there anything I need to change in my code?

Comment: Remove the second line `data.head()`

Comment: It still reports the same error that name 'data' is not defined

Comment: @Papernapkin23 are you sure that you want to use data and not radius?

Comment: @Papernapkin23 Elaborating on what Tajinder Singh said, you are getting the error because you havent defined the data variable before using it in the line ```data = pd.DataFrame(data)```. You probably want to use radius

Comment: I did substitute the term 'data' with the 'radius' but, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @TajinderSingh, I want to use radius

Comment: @Papernapkin23, could you please write again what your code is and what error you got now?